# Probability that red ball is picked at $4$-th attempt?

Tags: probability

**Question:**

> There is a bag and it contains $4$ red and $4$ blue balls. Randomly three balls are selected one by one without replacement from bag and kept aside. After that one ball is picked from the remaining $5$ balls, find the probability of this ball being red colored.

**Possible Solution I can think of:**

I can't figure this out, the catch here is that in first three attempts if all balls are blue, then we get $4/5$ probability in $4$-th attempt, and if all balls are chosen red in first three attempts then probability becomes $1/5$, but I am not able to figure out which one is the correct probability because there are multiple possible scenarios. How to solve such kind of question when so many different probabilities are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem using the concept of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) and the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability): if $E_1,E_2,\ldots$ is a collection of disjoint events whose union equals the entire sample space then:
$$P(A|E_1)P(E_1)+P(A|E_2)P(E_2)+\ldots = P(A)$$
Let us denote with $P(a_1a_2a_3)$, with $a_1,a_2,a_3\in\{B,R\}$ (here $B$ and $R$ indicate, respectively, the colors blue and red) the probability that the first ball picked has color $a_1$, the second $a_2$ and the third $a_3$, while with $P(R|a_1a_2a_3)$ the probability that the $4$-th ball picked is red **given that** the first has color $a_1$, the second $a_2$ and the third $a_3$.

So if $A$ is the event "the $4$-th ball picked is red", the law of total probability tells us that:
\begin{align*}P(A)&=P(R|RRR)\cdot P(RRR)\\&+P(R|BRR)\cdot P(BRR)+P(R|RBR)\cdot P(RBR)+P(R|RRB)\cdot P(RRB)\\&+P(R|BBR)\cdot P(BBR)+P(R|BRB)\cdot P(BRB)+P(R|RBB)\cdot P(RBB)\\&+P(R|BBB)\cdot P(BBB)
\end{align*}
It's easy to see that:

1. $P(R|RRR)=\frac{1}{5}$ and $P(RRR)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{7}\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{14}$
2. $P(R|BRR)=P(R|RBR)=P(R|RRB)=\frac{2}{5}$ and $P(BRR)=P(RBR)=P(RRB)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{7}$
3. $P(R|BBR)=P(R|BRB)=P(R|RBB)=\frac{3}{5}$ and $P(BBR)=P(BRB)=P(RBB)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{7}\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{7}$
4. $P(R|BBB)=\frac{4}{5}$ and $P(BBB)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{7}\frac{2}{6}=\frac{1}{14}$

So a simple calculation tells you that $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The first three balls are irrelevant.  You're just looking at one ball drawn from the bag. How you go about doing it doesn't matter, as long as none of the balls is more likely to be picked than any other.

Comment: so answer is coming out to be 0.5, correct me if I am wrong ?